# How to make an admin panel using Play framework 2.0/2.1

Tags: java, javascript, scala, playframework-2.0

I am doing with SCALA and Play Framework 2.1. I have doubt in mind that, is it possible to make an Admin panel using Play & SCALA?

An Admin panel may have CRUD. It will have some products. I need to manage all the Products through back-end.
I have worked with Play 1.2 & Play 2.1. but didn't got chance to work on ADMIN panel.

Is there any module available for Back-end.
Can anybody suggestion me on the same?

Comment: Can you add some more detail? An admin panel for what? What do you mean by "Back-end"?

Answer (score 4):

No, Play in general has no typical usage targeted, so there's no BE module or CRUD in Play 2, you need to create your panel yourself according to your needs.

Tip: fortunately there are available modules for authentication and authorization, so you don't need to create it from scratch, check for an example [Play Authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) for Java.

Easy way for building custom backends is using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and [Play's Forms](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaForms) although this approach is not as fast as CRUD known from Play 1.x - it gives you full flexibility with minimally higher cost.